# Server Client Communication between Android App and PHP Server

Tags: php, android

Guys I am creating an Online Android App, my server-side is taken care with php. Everything is going good. The app is working as per my concept.

Now I need to add a new feature in my app where i means the server need to know  if the user is online now in his android app. How can i achieve this. Please help me out.

In the app when a user first downloaded and run the app, he/she need to register first and then login, as soon as he logs in, I stored his login data in "SharedPreferences", so that no need for the user to login every-time he opens the app.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this method on Activity to keep knowledge that user is interacting with application (Online/Active/Not interacting, etc.). You can post your status to the server in this method.

```
@Override 
public void onUserInteraction() 
{ 
}
```

Comment: ur answer is really helpful, now i am googling to get its exact implementation. Thanks dude

Comment: ........one more help needed, how i know that the user has closed the app.

Comment: You can implement onDestroy() method.

Comment: You can also refer Auto Logout after defined time(minutes)https://github.com/pritamworld/AutoLogoutExample

Comment: Pritesh can u give me any idea of this - i want to call a php page using an url to send some data from the app in the onUserInteraction() and onDestroy() methods. How can i do that

Comment: https://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64